# Any potential issues using uitableview and uiwebview to show mini google map

Tags: ios, uitableview, google-maps

Im looking into having a tableview and a custom cell that has a webview control. The purpose of the webview would to show a google map inside the webview at some lat/long.

Could there be problematic with this approach? Memory issues?

Another approach would be having a uiimage and use the google map static api to generate the image and store the image on my server and have the app request the image via a URL.

I was hoping to avoid generating the images and storing them on my server and using directly the google map in a web view, but not sure what kind of issues i could run into with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is speed.  If your table view consists of rows and rows of MKMapViews, it will take time for each one to load as the user scrolls through them.  However, if there is only one it shouldn't be a problem.

The static image approach has the same problem but I think it might be slightly faster.

Comment: but im not using mkmapview at all .. its a regular uiwebview that is loading a url http://maps.google.com/mylatlong.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app in the App Store for a local festival that had many events at different venues. Given that the audience was from all over the world, and thus unknown in town, the app showed a map for each event. I solved this using an `MKMapView` inside a custom `UITableViewCell` and using an accessory disclosure button that would push a detailed map view onto the navigation controller. It worked well, but was a little slow. I would not recommend it for many such cells.

Screen shot: [image]

Comment: yeah thats why im not using an mkmapview inside my custom cell but was thinking of using an uiwebview pointing to a specific url .... and having like more than 500 data .. wonder if i could have huge problems like memory ???

Comment: Why exactly would you use a web view instead of a map kit view?

Comment: i thought maybe the mapkit would be heavier than a webview?

Comment: Although I have not measured, I find that hard to believe. The web view must parse and render HTML, CSS and JavaScript in addition to downloading and viewing map tiles.

Comment: I guess ill have to try it out then. My original implementation was a tableview using the mapkit .. i had like 500 data to display and it was a bit slow when scrolling ....

Comment: You'll have the same slowness issue regardless if you use a downloadable image, MkMapView or a UIWebView.  You will just need to try each a see which one is the fastest.